# Python Function raising ValueError if a float

Tags: python, function, collatz

I have written this Collatz conjecture sequence. It works but I need it to raise a ValueError if a float is entered instead of an integer (ex. 10.0 would raise an error but not 10). I have tried several things but can't seem to quite get it right. Thank you.

```
def Collatz(n):
    collatzlist = [n]
    if n > 0:
        while n > 1:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n / 2
            else:
                n = n * 3 + 1
            collatzlist.append(n)
    else:
        raise ValueError()

    return collatzlist
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: `if type(n) != int: raise ValueError()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check using `isinstance()`. If `n` is an instance of `float`  raise `ValueError`.

```
def Collatz(n):
    if isinstance(n, float):
        raise ValueError()
    collatzlist = [n]
    if n > 0:
        while n > 1:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n / 2
            else:
                n = n * 3 + 1
            collatzlist.append(n)
    

    return collatzlist
    raise NotImplementedError()
```